# How to add extra column actions in jquery jtable

Tags: jquery, jquery-jtable

I have been working on jquery jtables and having trouble in some conditions. I need to add two column tabs having button which do have their own action during click events. Can I do this with jquery jtable plugin api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can add extra column in JTable. [Here](http://jtable.org/ApiReference/FieldOptions#fopt-display) is example given for that.

```
TestColumn: {
    title: 'Test',
    display: function (data) {
        return '<a href="...">'; //here you can call JavaScript function using  onclick
    }
}
```